# sitecore 9.1 Xp1 Scaled (on premise ) Processing server throws error

Tags: processing

I have installed xp1 scaled topology on-premise successfully
and I see cm analytics default data displayed all 0.

I have a dedicated Reporting and Processing server, whenever I browse prc app I see the Sitecore page, but in the log, I see the following error. I have verified all client certificate thumbprint, access is all fine.

Query:- is there any configuration that needs to be updated in the Processing and reporting server specific to the below error?
could you please help

```
1824 13:13:53 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

Thanking with regards,
Avinash joseph

Comment: It looks like you don't have the proper certificate installed or thumbprint is not correct. Also if you run the script multiple times then you may have some extra unused certificates, try deleting those.

Comment: Adding to Mahendra point, please check your certificate issuer is installed as well on this processing server.

Comment: Yes that was certificate issue and only recognizable was the X mark in certificate , reinstalled and all worked fine